# Three-way full outer join in SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite

I have three tables with a common key field, and I need to join them on this key. Given SQLite doesn't have full outer or right joins, I've used the [full outer join without right join technique on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_join#Full_outer_join) with much success.

But I'm curious, how would one use this technique to join *three* tables by a common key? What are the efficiency impacts of this (the current query takes about ten minutes)?

Thanks!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If people stumble across this later, I ultimately tried using temporary tables after the first join, and then joined on this temporary table. It became a hassle, so I ultimately switched to PostgreSQL (which has full outer joins).

Comment: Changing database engine is not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create temporary table with all keys with UNION SELECT. And then LEFT JOIN to this temporary table other tables;

```
    CREATE TABLE a (
        tc INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        v INTEGER
    );
    CREATE TABLE b (
        tc NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        v INTEGER
    );
    CREATE TABLE c (
        tc NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        v INTEGER
    );
    INSERT INTO a (tc, v) VALUES(1, 10);
    INSERT INTO a (tc, v) VALUES(2, 20);
    INSERT INTO a (tc, v) VALUES(4, 40);

    INSERT INTO b (tc, v) VALUES(1, 100);
    INSERT INTO b (tc, v) VALUES(3, 300);
    INSERT INTO b (tc, v) VALUES(5, 500);

    INSERT INTO c (tc, v) VALUES(1, 1000);
    INSERT INTO c (tc, v) VALUES(3, 3000);
    INSERT INTO c (tc, v) VALUES(7, 7000);

    CREATE TEMP TABLE keys
    AS
    SELECT tc as tc FROM a
    UNION
    SELECT tc as tc FROM b
    UNION
    SELECT tc as tc FROM c;

    SELECT k.tc, a.v, b.v, c.v
      FROM keys as k
 LEFT JOIN a ON (k.tc = a.tc)
 LEFT JOIN b ON (k.tc = b.tc)
 LEFT JOIN c ON (k.tc = c.tc);
```